# Contradictory output in Python

Tags: python

I wrote this small program in python to display a decimal integer as the sorted list of its digits:

```
import math 
import sys
import os

l = []

def f(n):
    if (math.floor(n/ 10) == 0):
        l.append(n)
        return l
    else:
        l.append(n%10)
        return f(int((n - (n%10))/10))

def g(n):
    return sorted(f(n))

print( g(1) )
print ([1] == [1])
print (g(1) == g(1))
```

It seems like upon running it, it should answer `[1], True, True`.
When I run it, it gives me the seemingly contradictory answers `[1], True, False`.  Why does that happen?

Comment: Python is not functional so things like this are possible.

Comment: @EliSadoff: the term 'functional' does not mean what you think it means. Python doesn't have [*pure functions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), is what you are trying to say.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, I meant to say that python is not purely functional. In the way that `g(1) == g(1)` in a purely functional language will always be true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are altering a global `l`, then return a sorted copy. `l` keeps growing:

```
>>> g(1)
[1]
>>> l
[1]
>>> g(1)
[1, 1]
>>> l
[1, 1]
>>> g(1)
[1, 1, 1]
>>> l
[1, 1, 1]
```

`[1, 1]` is not equal to `[1, 1, 1]`.

Don't use a global list if you want to produce a single-element list each time you call `g()`.

Comment: Indeed if the code would have been `f(1) == f(1)` it would have worked :-D

Comment: @6502: yup, because then a reference to the same list is returned, rather than a copy.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(g(1))
print(g(1))
print(g(1))
```

Outputs:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

Because you're using a single global list `l` that changes every time you run `f` and doesn't get reset.